# Apache can't access host directory, but I have Read perm for all

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, file-permissions

So basically i have a dir like this:

```
/home/user1/www
```

this is owned by root with the following perm: `drwxr-xr-x`  this means everyone can read it.

inside i have the .htaccess (still owned by root) with this perm: `-rw-r--r--` this also mean everyone can read it.

If I try to open this website, Apache 2.4 says:

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

But why if I have read permission for everyone?

Comment: Are you sure www-data has read permission to `/home` and `/home/user1` ?

Comment: if i do chmod -R 777 /home/user1/www then apache works :/